# Can't share network printer from windows 11 to windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, drivers, printer, windows-11

I have a Kyocera TASKalfa 220 plugged into a Windows 11 PC and I want to share it with a Windows 7 one. I can share files but when I try to add it (the printer) to Windows 7 through the network it tells me **"Windows can't connect to printer please check its name"**.

- I tried to restart the printer spooler
- I allowed non administrator to install driver
- I did configure RPC
- I activated SMB

OS version **Windows 11 22H2**

What am I missing?

Keep in mind that Kyocera provides no driver for Windows 11 so I use the one that came from windows update.

**Edit 1 :**

When I run Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SMB1Protocol in PowerShell it returns True. (on Windows 11)

-I can share files between windows 11 and windows 7
-In windows 7 PC i can see the shared printer that is connected to windows 11 but when i try to add it. it throw an error *which i cited on the start of the thread

**EDIT 2 :**

I do still believe that Windows 11 is capable to have SMB V1 enabled see screenshot :

[image: scrot]

Comment: Windows 11 is SMB V3 or thereabouts and Windows 7 is SMB V1 most likely and that is why print sharing does not work. Get a Print Server box and put the printer on your network. Best way by far,

Comment: @John i am a young man doing an intership (i'm still new) in a small office i can't ask them for spending just tell me if there are no other option if it's the case i will have no other choice than to move on on another task (just to clear my mind)  :/

Comment: @John but why when i run Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SMB1Protocol in powershell it return True?

Comment: You have shared files, but have you actually [shared the printer](https://www.wintips.org/how-to-share-printer-in-windows-11/)?  Have you installed the driver to [Windows 7](https://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/en/support/downloads.name-L2V1L2VuL21mcC9UQVNLQUxGQTIyMA==.html)? Can the Win7 system see the printer as a shared resource of the W11 at all? What exact error message do you get (check Event Viewer)? Please don't answer questions and add new info in comments, instead [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1775701/edit) the question so all relevant info is immediately available.

Comment: Which system do you run the PowerShell command in - Win 11? Please update the question to clarify.

Comment: why when i run Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SMB1Protocol in powershell it return True?    ...  Windows 11 does not support SMB1

Comment: doing an intership (i'm still new) in a small office i can't ask them for spending   .....  I moved customers off print sharing many years ago and they were so happy. Get an employee to make the case.

Comment: @Peregrino69 i added the info that you asked about please check

Answer (score 0):

You have confirmed in a comment that your issue is for a small company.

In a business environment, printers work best on a network. That way no particular computer needs to be ON for printing to work.

As more people move to Windows 11, networked printing is even more essential.

Get a small Print Server (normally not real expensive).  Put the Printer on the Print Server.

Now put the Print Driver on each system (Windows has most Print Drivers) matched to the particular system.

I converted customers to network printing many years ago and they were very happy with the results. Much more productive (saves time).

Comment: I have looked up on the internet for available print server in my country and found that I will suggest to them the TP-LINK TL-PS110U but just to be sure do i need to configure it through a web panel like we do with routers? or is it just plug and play (i mean just add printer in the window network window) i appreciate your help

Comment: Attach and configure the print server on your network and then attach the printer. Then you should be able to add printers at the workstations.

Comment: You may now consider acknowledging my answer that I provided you.

Comment: @Capacity213 How to configure a print server depends on the print server itself. The instructions are usually in the manual. [Here's](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201812/20181210/1910012231_TL-PS110U_QIG_V3.pdf) the one for the TP-Link you mentioned (direct PDF link). "Acknowledging" the answer means [accepting](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I haven't accepted as a solution (yet) just because he proposed an alternative solution so i wish that maybe other users give their 2 cent to  be sure that it is not possible (printer sharing between windows 7 and 11) looking at screenshot that i shared SMB v1 can be enabled (or at least i do believe)

Comment: @Peregrino69 what i don't comprehend is that file sharing between windows 7 and windows 11 work but printer sharing don't? isn't it an all or nothing feature i mean it's whether it works or it doesn't there are no between :(

Comment: That may possibly depend on the printer firmware, and is one main reason why network printing works so much better

Answer (score 0):

Just made it work.
Windows 11 printing to Windows 7 shared printers.
File and printer sharing enabled on both boxes.
Network discovery enabled on both boxes.
Windows 11 will not see anything on 7. Not a problem.
HP printer shared on 7.
Zebra tag printer shared on 7.
Zebra label printer shared on 7.
On the 11 box add printer using manual add.
Choose 'Select a shared printer by name'.
Follow the example by typing \\ipaddressof7box\  (make sure you use the third backlash).
Choose browse.
The printers shared on 7 will list in a box.
Choose the desired printer.
Choosing [next] will install drivers and allow you to finish the install.
Repeat for more printers.
My printers are old. The HP driver will not install on 11 but installs just fine on 7. HTH!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).